# How to save Login credentials in SQLite for allowing offline Login

Tags: ios4, sqlite, ipad-2

i am quit a newbie in iOS development and using login view where login credentials are getting authenticated using web services. I have to implement the same thing in offline mode also but how to do that using SQLlite any type of suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well u can make use of [NSUserDefaults][1]

[1]: http://zcentric.com/2008/08/20/using_nsuserdefaults/      .. Its the easiest way using objective C